# Node.js How to create email accounts (Disposable) dynamically & receive emails through them?

Tags: node.js, email, smtp, imap

I want to create temporary, short-lived email addresses and receive mail at those addresses. These addresses should be created dynamically (i.e. I can control what those addresses are).

How can I use Node.JS to dynamically create hundreds of emails on a domain?

Comment: I have been trying to use Ad Hoc Email Server (AHEM) but not sure if this is doable with AHEM.